# fancybox ensure fancybox-image isn't cached

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, caching, fancybox-2

I'm running into issues where fancybox is loading a cached image.  I would like to ensure that the image is not cached before it appears on the page, but I haven't been success with trying to accomplish this through its various callbacks (beforeShow, afterShow, afterLoad, beforeLoad).

This is what I currently have:

```
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
          helpers: {
            overlay: {
              locked: false
            }
          }, 
          beforeShow: function(){
            if($('.fancybox-image').length>0){
              console.log($('.fancybox-image').attr('src'));
              clearCacheImages('fancybox');
            }
          }
        });

    function clearCacheImages(source){
      if(source == "all"){
        // console.log('loading all images');
        jQuery('img').each(function(){  
          jQuery(this).attr('src',jQuery(this).attr('src')+ '?' + (new Date()).getTime());  
        });  
      }else if(source=="fancybox"){
        // console.log('loading fancybox image: ' + $('.fancybox-image').attr('src'));
        $('.fancybox-image').attr('src',$('.fancybox-image').attr('src')+ '?' + (new Date()).getTime());
      }

    }
```

When I click the next button in the fancybox slideshow, it shows the previous image rather than the first.  Anyone know how and when to ensure that the fancybox image isn't cached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do to always load a non-cached image in fancybox is to dynamically add a version `?v=` trialing parameter to the fancybox `href` using the `beforeLoad` callback like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeLoad: function () {
        this.href = this.href + "?v=" + new Date().getTime()
    }
});
```

That way, fancybox will always (re)load the image instead of using a cached one.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7Jh2S/)**

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I needed, thank you!  I was missing the this.href element.